# Change the label text (Search & Filter wordpress plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using a Wordpress plugin - [Search & Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/) to filter the content on portfolio page. The content can be filtered by category and tag.

Basically, what I want is to remove the text "portfolio" on drop down menu as shown below. Which mean change the text from "All Portfolio Categories" to "All Categories".

I have go through the plugin code, but still cannot find it. Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this in the shortcode:
all_items_labels="All Categories, All tags" (or whatever text you need to fill in)

Probably this is the complete shortcode you need:
[searchandfilter fields="category,post_tag" all_items_labels="All Categories, All tags"]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To replace the drop down, Use the code below

```
[searchandfilter fields="search,product_tag,product_cat" submit_label ="Search" search_placeholder="Search for a service" all_items_labels=",Location,Categories"]
```

in `all_items_labels=",`comma after `all_items_labels="` is due to my search bar. As there is nothing to change in that, keeping that `,` will take it as the first position and will move to the second and third replacement. You can use similar structure to change any label of any position.